# QBOnline + Invoice exported via API: Account configuration defaults not populating

Tags: api, quickbooks-online, invoice

I have a database solution that exports Invoices to Quickbooks Online (QBO) using the Invoices API. The Invoices generally come through OK, with a few exceptions.

There are various defaults defined in the QBO account.  E.g. a default BCC email; default 'Online Payment' options set.  I would expect that these defaults would be honored and applied to new Invoices imported into QBO via the API, assuming that there aren't any values explicitly being defined by the Invoice JSON object that is sent from the database system.

1. Email BCC: the QBO account profile has a BCC value defined. On Invoices created in QBO, it correctly sets the 'Customer -> CC/BCC' value to this setting. But Invoices created through the API do not set the BCC.
2. 'Online Payments' section - Credit Card / Bank Transfers:  the account is configured to have Credit Card and Bank Transfers options set to default to On. Assuming that the Invoice JSON exported from my system does not explicitly set these flags, it should be setting them based on the defaults they have configured. It's not - they are both being left 'Off'.

Does anyone have suggestions on what the QBO account profile defaults should be doing vs what my export is resulting in?

Here's the exchange to QBO (URL, cURL, JSON):

FullURL:

```
https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/<realmID>/invoice?minorversion=4
```

cURL:

```
-D $dump_header -X POST
-H \"Authorization: Bearer <AccessToken>\"
-H \"Accept: application/json\"
-H \"Content-Type: application/json\"
-d <jsonObject>
```

JSON data object:

```
 {
    "BillAddr": {
        "City": "New York",
        "Country": "USA",
        "CountrySubDivisionCode": "NY",
        "Line1": "",
        "Line2": "Production LLC",
        "Line3": "123 W. Main Street",
        "Line4": "",
        "PostalCode": "05555"
    },
    "CustomerMemo": {
        "value": "Thank you for your business! We look forward to working with you again Inv#: 1234"
    },
    "CustomerRef": {
        "value": "9999"
    },
    "DueDate": "2023-03-31",
    "Line": [
        {
            "Amount": 800,
            "Description": "10/01/22 PD Load",
            "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
            "LineNum": 1,
            "SalesItemLineDetail": {
                "ItemRef": {
                    "name": "PD Load",
                    "value": "557"
                },
                "Qty": 20,
                "UnitPrice": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "Amount": 4480,
            "Description": "10/01/22 DR Edit",
            "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
            "LineNum": 2,
            "SalesItemLineDetail": {
                "ItemRef": {
                    "name": "DR Edit",
                    "value": "549"
                },
                "Qty": 112,
                "UnitPrice": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "Amount": 1600,
            "Description": "10/01/22 BG Edit",
            "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
            "LineNum": 3,
            "SalesItemLineDetail": {
                "ItemRef": {
                    "name": "BG Edit",
                    "value": "491"
                },
                "Qty": 40,
                "UnitPrice": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "Amount": 2240,
            "Description": "10/01/22 Sfx Edit",
            "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
            "LineNum": 4,
            "SalesItemLineDetail": {
                "ItemRef": {
                    "name": "Sfx Edit",
                    "value": "49"
                },
                "Qty": 56,
                "UnitPrice": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "Amount": 2240,
            "Description": "10/01/22 Sound Design",
            "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
            "LineNum": 5,
            "SalesItemLineDetail": {
                "ItemRef": {
                    "name": "Sound Design",
                    "value": "537"
                },
                "Qty": 56,
                "UnitPrice": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "Amount": -1000,
            "Description": "10/01/22 Discount on Services",
            "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
            "LineNum": 14,
            "SalesItemLineDetail": {
                "ItemRef": {
                    "name": "Discount - Services",
                    "value": "380"
                },
                "Qty": 1,
                "UnitPrice": -1000
            }
        }
    ],
    "SalesTermRef": {
        "value": "8"
    },
    "TxnDate": "2023-03-02"
}
```

Here's the account 'Preferences' object, showing that the default BCC is defined (down at the bottom, "SalesEmailBCC"):

```
    {
    "Preferences": {
        "AccountingInfoPrefs": {
            "UseAccountNumbers": false,
            "TrackDepartments": false,
            "ClassTrackingPerTxn": false,
            "ClassTrackingPerTxnLine": false,
            "FirstMonthOfFiscalYear": "January",
            "TaxYearMonth": "January",
            "CustomerTerminology": "Customers"
        },
        "ProductAndServicesPrefs": {
            "ForSales": true,
            "ForPurchase": true,
            "QuantityWithPriceAndRate": true,
            "QuantityOnHand": true,
            "RevenueRecognition": false,
            "RevenueRecognitionFrequency": "MONTHLY"
        },
        "SalesFormsPrefs": {
            "UsingProgressInvoicing": false,
            "CustomField": [
                {
                    "CustomField": [
                        {
                            "Name": "SalesFormsPrefs.UseSalesCustom3",
                            "Type": "BooleanType",
                            "BooleanValue": true
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "SalesFormsPrefs.UseSalesCustom1",
                            "Type": "BooleanType",
                            "BooleanValue": true
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "SalesFormsPrefs.UseSalesCustom2",
                            "Type": "BooleanType",
                            "BooleanValue": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "CustomField": [
                        {
                            "Name": "SalesFormsPrefs.SalesCustomName3",
                            "Type": "StringType",
                            "StringValue": "Client Job Number"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "SalesFormsPrefs.SalesCustomName2",
                            "Type": "StringType",
                            "StringValue": "Sales Rep (inactive)"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "SalesFormsPrefs.SalesCustomName1",
                            "Type": "StringType",
                            "StringValue": "P.O. Number"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "CustomTxnNumbers": false,
            "SalesEmailBcc": {
                "Address": "abc@r.com,hij@r.com,bbb@r.com"
            },
```

[image: Online Payments]

[image: Missing BCC]

[image: Example of Online Payment config]

Comment: Bump.  No answers yet?

Comment: Bumping via comments may not be helpful...

Comment: Bump.   <Minimum comment length padding>

Comment: Bump again - maybe.  Hopefully.